# In regression analysis, does the i.i.d. assumption still hold if only the error term, but not the independent variables, are randomly distributed?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

In regression analysis, can the error terms still be independently, identically distributed (i.i.d.) if the independent variables are not from a random draw?

Comment: It depends: are you assuming the error terms are independent of the independent variables or are you only assuming they are not correlated with them?

Comment: Thanks, @whuber. To answer your question: I'm assuming all independent variables are uncorrelated with the error term.

Comment: What sense does "uncorrelated" make when you are explicitly assuming the independent variables aren't random?